# add pound symbol before the number

Tags: jquery

i am adding two values. calculation is coming correctly but i want to display the result with pound symbol. i added i like this but not working.

my html is

```
<td class="#perMonth">&pound 0</td>

$('.totalIncome').on('keyup',function(e) {
        var income1 = $('#monthlyIncome').val(),
            income2 = $('#otherIncome').val(),
            $perMonth = $('#perMonth');

            if(income1 == '' && income2 == '') {
                $perMonth.html(0);
            } else if(!isNaN(income1 == '') && income2 == '') {
                $perMonth.html(parseInt(income1));
                $('#totalIncom').html('&pound;'parseInt(income1));
            } else if(!isNaN(income2 == '') && income1 == '') {
                $perMonth.html('&pound;'parseInt(income2));
                $('#totalIncom').html('&pound;'parseInt(income2));
            } else {
                $perMonth.html('&pound;'parseInt(income1)+'&pound;'parseInt(income2));
                $('#totalIncom').html('&pound;'parseInt(income1)+'&pound;'parseInt(income2));
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need + for string concatenation:

So instead of

```
$('#totalIncome').html('&pound;'parseInt(income1));
```

You need

```
$('#totalIncome').html('&pound;' + parseInt(income1));
```

Comment: And it looks like you spelled '#totalIncome' as '#totalIncom' in there a few places too.